# KeyError with integer tuples as keys

Tags: python

Following is the code

```
values = { (0,0) : "_", (0,1) : "_", (0,2) : "_",
           (1,0) : "_", (1,1) : "_", (1,2) : "_",
           (2,0) : "_", (2,1) : "_", (2,2) : "_" }


def draw_matrix():
    matrix = "\t ___ ___ ___\n\t|_{(0,0)}_|_{(0,1)}_|_{(0,2)}_|\n\t|_{(1,0)}_|_{(1,1)}_|_{(1,2)}_|\n\t|_{(2,0)}_|_{(2,1)}_|_{(2,2)}_|"
    print(matrix.format(**values))
    print("\nUse numpad keys to enter your mark")

draw_matrix()
```

When I access values of keys individually, it works fine. But, I can't unpack this dictionary using .format() for some reason.

```
KeyError: '(0,0)'
```

It's the same if I use numbers. This is gonna be a tic-tac-toe game so I used the numpad keys previously. I cannot use the tuples as strings because I'll need to use them to check for winning conditions. That works perfectly, though.

Comment: You're incorrectly using keyword arguments because the `format` method has no keyword `(0, 0)` for example.

Comment: Yes, but the dictionary has. I used a similar method on a dictionary that had 'name' and 'occupation' keywords and it worked. So why not here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The simplest way to solve your problem is add whitespace between tuple elements in matrix string so `(0,0)` => `(0, 0)` and then convert tuples to string representations:

```
matrix = "\t ___ ___ ___\n\t|_{(0, 0)}_|_{(0, 1)}_|_{(0, 2)}_|\n\t|_{(1, 0)}_|_{(1, 1)}_|_{(1, 2)}_|\n\t|_{(2, 0)}_|_{(2, 1)}_|_{(2, 2)}_|"
print(matrix.format(**{str(k): v for k,v in values.items()}))
 ___ ___ ___
|___|___|___|
|___|___|___|
|___|___|___|
```

Although this approach occasionally works fine, this code might be broken in future versions of python (as [user2357112](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2357112/user2357112) noticed). So you should use valid keyword arguments in `format` function. For example:

```
matrix = "\t ___ ___ ___\n\t|_{c0_0}_|_{c0_1}_|_{c0_2}_|\n\t|_{c1_0}_|_{c1_1}_|_{c1_2}_|\n\t|_{c2_0}_|_{c2_1}_|_{c2_2}_|"
print(matrix.format(**{"c%d_%d"%k: v for k,v in values.items()}))
```

Comment: While this works, it's not supposed to. `**` should only be used with dicts where all keys are valid Python keyword arguments. Future Python versions might break it.

Comment: (And yes, they really might put in a check just to break code like this, even at the cost of runtime efficiency. They did it once already to break `dict(d1, **d2)`.)

Comment: `0_0` isn't a valid Python keyword argument; keyword arguments have to start with a letter or an underscore. Something like `c0_0` or `c00` would work.

Comment: My fault, speed is not always good. Thank you for corrections!

Comment: The reason i wanna use tuples made of integers is because that way, it'll be easier to check the logic for winning conditions. Although, the code works, I don't get why I get a key error even though the keys exist. **values should work fine.

Answer (score 0):

The solution that ipoteka provided works, thanks for that. I also wanted to figure out what's the reason tuples can't be used as key values. They seem to work individually(values[(0, 0)]) but not when unpacking the dictionary.

Tuples can be used as keys because they have unique hash values, but they cannot be used in places that require identifiers, such as format()